# Retrieve the login flow metadata using vs code

Tags: custom

Is it possible to retrieve the login flow metadata using VS Code?

Thanks,
Raja G

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask). You will need to [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/420079/edit) your question to include more details.

Comment: You want to retrieve a flow using VS Code?

Comment: @prem22 Not flow its custom login flow, So i need to retrieve the login flow meta data using vs code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both metadata (objects and records) and flow can be retrieved via VS Code:

- retrieve mdt object as any CustomObject, with it's API name: sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:mdtobjectAPIname
- retrieve mdt records: sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomMetadat:mdtobjectname.recordAPIname
- retrieve flow: sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Flow:flowAPIname

Comment: @ mpaun I need login flow meta data not flow builder meta data

Comment: Reading the docs, it seems it should be a part of the profile: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm#loginflow_title

Comment: Thank you for your help @mpaun